# CakePHP Calling a function in a model when you're in a controller

Tags: php, cakephp

I am getting this error when calling a function to a model.

```
Database Error

Error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'singleBlockWeekly' at line 1

SQL Query: singleBlockWeekly
```

This is my Controller

```
class BlackoutController extends CalendarAppController
{
    var $uses = array('Studio','Blackout','BlackoutRepeatTypeDetails','Calendar.Event');
    var $components = array('Accesscontrol','RequestHandler');
    function event_checker()
    {
        $start_date = $this->request->data['start_date'];
        $end_date = $this->request->data['end_date'];
        $endsOn = $this->request->data['endsOn'];
        $repeatType = $this->request->data['repeatType'];
        $blockType = $this->request->data['blockType'];
        $frequency = $this->request->data['freq'];
        $repeatDays = $this->request->data['repeatDays'];

        #single type 
        if($blockType == "single"){
            if($repeatType == "weekly"){
                $dates = $this->Blackout->singleBlockWeekly($start_date,$endsOn,$repeatDays,$frequency);
                debug($dates);
                die;
            }
        }
     }
}
```

This is my `Model`

```
class Blackout extends CalendarAppModel
{
   var $name = 'Blackout';
   var $useTable = false;
   function singleBlockWeekly($startDate,$endDate,$repeatEvery = array(),$freq)
   {
     /*my code here...brevity...*/
   }
}
```

So i'm just doing here is just calling the singleBlockWeekly function in the Blackout Model. I'm wondering why am I getting the weird SQL error even if I don't have any SQL related code on the `singleBlockWeekly` function?

Your help will be greatly appreciated! Thanks! :)

Comment: can you please post your SQL query for this ?

Comment: That's the weird thing, i have no SQL query on this one, but it is giving me an SQL error.

Comment: inside this function "singleBlockWeekly" have you written any find query ? Or please add the line as  $this->loadModel('Blackout'); before that calling the function

Comment: Nope. There is no find query or any database related function/code in it.

Comment: try by placing `public` instead of `var`

Answer (score 2):

I assume this is a plugin?
Than you cannot just include it as 'Blackout', you need to use the documented plugin syntax 'Calendar.Blackout'.
Otherwise you will load an AppModel instance which, of course, does not have this method.

You could have found that out yourself if you had debugged the model instance:

```
debug($this->Blackout);
```

This SQL error is always an indicator of a misuse of model include statements.

Comment: I'm just being careless! I have 2 the same function name on my model, and it is giving me a weird error about class declaration has been nested, something like that. Actually, I already tried your suggestion about putting a Calendar.Blackout, I already put that one on the $uses part. The problem was that I was getting this error Class declarations may not be nested.. But then again, I noticed I have 2 functions having the same name so I thought that worsen the problem, but I already have the correct declaration, only having an error that is caused by 2 the same function name

Comment: Either way you need to be more careful with your declarations if you are using plugin classes.

Answer (score 1):

Problem in loading Model, SO try this

```
$this->loadModel('Blackout');
$dates = $this->Blackout->singleBlockWeekly($start_date,$endsOn,$repeatDays,$frequency);
```